# Быстрое вычитание списков

Tags: python, массивы, списки

Известны списки `A` и `B`.

Необходимо получить список `C = A – B`.

Есть следующая реализация:

```
for i in A:
    if not (i in B):
        C.append(i)
```

В случае, когда количество элементов списков `A` и `B` высоко (порядка `100 000` и выше), способ естественно работает очень медленно.

Возможно ли реализовать подобный поиск быстрее?

Если да, то как именно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно делать это через множество, будет намного быстрее. Например:

```
def quest():
    A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    B = [1, 2, 3, 15, 16, 10, 20]
    C = list(set(A) - set(B))
    print(C)
```

Результат:

> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Тестировал на списках с > 200,000 элементов. Сработало за 1 сек.

Comment: Результаты работы способов почему-то не совпадают. На больших списках строк.

Comment: Я вас понял. Так как это множество то элементы не могут повторятся. А это значит что они будут встречаться не больше 1 раза. В вашем коде если есть 2 одинаковые строки, они попадают в С. В моём же нет.

Comment: @Denis это решение не сохраняет ни порядок элементов ни их количество в `A`.

Answer (score 13):

`i in B` это `O(m)` операция для списков (`m = len(B)`). Поэтому ваш код это `O(n * m)` алгоритм (`n = len(A)`), то есть для длин списков ~`100_000` (10<sup>5</sup>) ваша реализация вычитания списков займёт порядка `10_000_000_000` (10<sup>10</sup>) операций. Если при работе с чуть бОльшими списками в телефоне вдруг всё начинает тормозить, когда для маленьких списков всё летает, то одно из вероятных объяснений, что программист использовал квадратичный алгоритм вместо линейного (или квази-линейного).

Можно значительно улучшить производительность (если все элементы списка хэшируются) с помощью [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
Bset = frozenset(B)
C = [item for item in A if item not in Bset]  # C = A - B
```

`item in Bset` это [`O(1)` операция (в среднем)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity). Поэтому `C` список вычисляется за `O(n + m)` (линейный алгоритм), что значительно лучше `O(n * m)` для больших `B`.

Обратите внимание, что `set(A)` не вызывается, иначе получатся результаты отличные от кода в вашем вопросе, если в `A` есть повторяющиеся элементы или если вы хотите исходный порядок в `A` сохранить:

```
>>> A = "abracadabra"
>>> B = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> Bset = frozenset(B)
>>> [item for item in A if item not in Bset]
['r', 'd', 'r']
```

Обратите внимание, `'r'` встречается дважды в результате и относительный порядок `'r'` и `'d'` сохранён.

Если элементы не являются хэшируемыми (к примеру вложенные списки), то можно отсортировать `B` и использовать [двоичный поиск](https://stackoverflow.com/q/212358/4279), чтобы определить присутствует ли элемент в отсортированной последовательности:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

def contains(sorted_seq, item):
    i = bisect_left(sorted_seq, item)
    return i != len(sorted_seq) and sorted_seq[i] == item
```

Пример:

```
>>> A = map(list, "abracadabra")
>>> B = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
>>> Bsorted = sorted(B)
>>> [item for item in A if not contains(Bsorted, item)]
[['r'], ['d'], ['r']]
```

Это `O((n  + m) * log m)` алгоритм. log() функция достаточно медленно растёт, к примеру, *log10(10<sup>5</sup>) == 5* Поэтому не измеряя производительность, сложно сказать какой код (на основе set или sorted) быстрее на заданных входных списках, платформе.

Если дополнительно порядок элементов в `B` списке не определён (`sorted()` не работает) и можно только сравнивать элементы напрямую (`a == b`), то придётся использовать `O(n * m)` алгоритм аналогичный приведённому в вопросе:

```
>>> A = [1, "a", 1]
>>> B = [[], 1]
>>> [item for item in A if item not in B]
['a']
```

Как `set(B)` так и `sorted(B)` не работают в этом случае.

Стоит заметить, что `C` в примере (`['a']`) не содержит единицу хотя она встречается два раза в `A` списке и только один раз в `B`.

---

Чтобы учесть число повторений в  `B`:

```
C = []
for item in A:
    try:
        B.remove(item)
    except ValueError:
        C.append(item)  # item not in B
```

В этом случае `C == ['a', 1]`, а не `['a']`. Код разрушает `B`. Алгоритм также `O(n * m)`.

Для хэшируемых элементов, чтобы учесть количество повторений элементов в `B`, можно в этом случае [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) использовать [как мультимножество](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE):

```
from collections import Counter

A = "abracadabra"
B = ['a', 'b', 'c']
Bcount = Counter(B)
C = []
for item in A:
    if Bcount[item] == 0:
        C.append(item)
    else:
        Bcount[item] -= 1
```

Результат `C == ['r', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'r', 'a']` отличается от `C == ['r', 'd', 'r']` полученного выше алгоритмом, который не учитывает количество повторений в `B`.

---

Если порядок элементов в результате не важен, то можно упростить код:

```
C = list((Counter(A) - Counter(B)).elements())
```

Возможный результат: `C == ['b', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'd']`. С точностью до порядка элементов внутри `C`, он совпадает с предыдущим примером. Оба алгоритма линейные — `О(m + n)`.

Так как порядок не сохраняется, то имеет смысл использовать просто:

```
C = Counter(A) - Counter(B)
# -> Counter({'a': 4, 'r': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
```

так как иначе использование списка для `C` может создать впечатление, что порядок элементов учитывается.

---

Если не нужно учитывать ни порядок ни количество повторений, то разницу списков можно найти, используя set (множество — разновидность [@Alban ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642640/23044)):

```
C = set(A).difference(B)
# -> {'d', 'r'}
```

---

Видно, что в зависимости от желаемого определения вычитания для списков, разность разные значения принимает:

```
A = "abracadabra"
B = ['a', 'b', 'c']
# C = A - B
# -> {'d', 'r'} # нет порядка, нет повторений
# -> Counter({'a': 4, 'r': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1}) # нет порядка
# -> ['r', 'd', 'r']  # порядок сохранён, но без учёта повторений в B
# -> ['r', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'r', 'a'] # порядок + с учётом повторений в B
```

В разных ситуациях разные определения могут быть полезны. Явной очевидной предпочтительной семантики здесь нет — вероятно поэтому операция вычитания (`A - B`) не определена для списков в Питоне.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так будет быстрее(массив С выходит такой же):

```
import itertools

C = list(itertools.filterfalse(B.__contains__, iter(A)))
```

Comment: Не думаю, что быстрее будет на больших объемах, чем вариант с `list` и  `set`.

Comment: @And: это квадратичное решение (`O(len(A) * len(B))`), поэтому оно  точно проиграет линейным решениям, использующим set, Counter (если они применимы) для достаточно больших A, B.

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

C = list(itertools.filterfalse(B.__contains__, iter(A)))
```

Так он правильно работает со строками, потому что при варианте

```
C = list(set(A) - set(B))
```

происходит перестановка элиментов в конечном списке, а это, в свою очередь, может исказить информацию, а в первом варианте элементы списка остаются на своих местах.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/857895)

Comment: Зачем вы повторяете код и рассуждения из других ответов?