# Python уникализация list

Tags: python

Есть огромный массив, в котором много дублей, нет ли в `python'e` аналога функции `array_unique()` из `php`?
Не могу найти ответ на мой вопрос

Comment: Порядок элементов в массиве сохранять обязательно или нет?

Comment: @andreymal не обязательно

Comment: все элементы в списке хэшируемые? Определён ли порядок элементов? Связанный вопрос [Быстрое вычитание списков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/642636/23044)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Функция set](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-set) (множество) удалит дубликаты:

```
items = [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(items)  # [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]

items = list(set(items))
print(items)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: так как порядок элементов не сохраняется, то можно как set оставить результат, без вызова list если нет явной необходимости.