# Python. Вычитание из списка список учитывая индексы

Tags: python, список

Как вычесть из списка список по определенным индексам. Не знаю как точно сформулировать, проще привести пример:

```
l = [10, 25, 50, 100, 20] # Список
n = [3, 7] # Числа
i = [0, 4] # Индексы
```

То есть на выходе должно получиться следущее

```
l = [7, 25, 50, 100, 13]
```

Как это осуществить и как это называется "по-нормальному"?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Быстрое вычитание списков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/642636/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

конкретно под вашу задачу можно попробовать так

```
l = [10, 25, 50, 100, 20] # Список
n = [3, 7] # Числа
j = [0, 4] # Индексы   

for i, m in enumerate(j):
    l[m] -= n[i]
print(l) # [7, 25, 50, 100, 13]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for i, n in zip(indices, numbers):
    L[i] -= n
```